# 404 Error on page redirection after creating an account - slashes in URL escaped

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, character-escaping

I was on a question on apple.stackexchange.com, and decided to create an account because I wanted to give it an upvote. So I:

1. Clicked "login" at the top
2. Clicked the Google button
3. Allowed Google to send my email to SE

At this point SE said no account existed, and asked if I wanted to create an account. I clicked Confirm. Then I was redirected to a 404 error. It looks like the entire URL is URL-encoded:

```
http://apple.stackexchange.com%2fquestions%2f2022%2fis-there-an-app-or-another-way-to-make-an-ipod-touch-or-iphone-emulate-an-older-i/
```

<sub>(I'm reporting this here because I'm assuming this is common code that is not specific to the Apple site.)</sub>

Comment: This *just* happened to me during regular login redirection, so it isn't isolated to creating a new account.

Comment: thanks jon. i just assumed it was a new account creation issue since it's probably rarer than login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now fixed, and I believe it was a regression.