# Return URL is broken (escaping more characters than needed)

Tags: bug, login, redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [404 Error on page redirection after creating an account - slashes in URL escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99774/404-error-on-page-redirection-after-creating-an-account-slashes-in-url-escaped)

Steps to reproduce

1. Logoff
2. Go to [jQuery selection. Find element after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991513/jquery-selection-find-element-after-another/)
3. Login. Url is:

   https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions%2f5991513%2fjquery-selection-find-element-after-another
4. Page is redirected to:

   http://stackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f5991513%2fjquery-selection-find-element-after-another/

Firefox 5, Windows 7

Comment: Seems strange that this is a duplicate of a problem that has already been fixed.

Comment: @Cody - unless the fix hasn't been deployed to Stack Overflow yet, though I've just checked and the version numbers seem to match.

Comment: Tested at `2011-07-26 13:28:37Z` and `2011-07-26 13:57:03Z`: still doesn't work.

Comment: Tested at `2011-07-27 13:39:48Z`, it is fixed.

Comment: We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)