# Bug on sign up from a random url

Tags: bug, login

I tried to sign up on stackoverflow.com from this url :
[How to avoid "ls: write error: Broken pipe" with php exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296809/how-to-avoid-ls-write-error-broken-pipe-with-php-exec)

I clicked on "sign up" on top, then "click here to sign up".
I wrote my infos and clicked on "Create stack exchange account".

I then arrived on a page telling me "wrong link" or something like this (very sorry, I closed the window), and giving no info about my account creation. The account was not created, I didn't receive a mail, I couldn't log in.
The message was quoting the url I was coming from.

Then I went on the site's homepage, clicked "sign up", etc, and the account creation worked perfectly.

I used the same login and mail and it worked, so it show again the 1st try didn't work (I think).

Looks like this bug has returned: [404 Error on page redirection after creating an account - slashes in URL escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99774/152859)

Comment: Any chance you experienced [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99774/152859)?

Comment: Indeed it looks like the same bug. Sadly, it's not fixed as it happened to me a few minutes ago.

Comment: Cheers, I've added it to the post.

Comment: Hmmm.... I just went through exactly the process you described; my account was created perfectly...  http://stackoverflow.com/users/3008258/user3008258 - I'm not saying "it didn't happen" - I'm just saying that "it isn't endemically broken"

Comment: @Marc but question is were you redirected to the question you were viewing, or to 404 page due to escaped slashes?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd actually, neither; I ended up at the home page

Comment: @Marc weird... maybe it's dependant on the selected OpenID provider?